# Card game Probability: Having a second war after a first war

Tags: probability, card-games

I was wondering about the probability of getting two wars.  The way the game works is, both players get $26$ cards, and flip one card over, whoever has the largest card value, takes both cards and puts them underneath the deck.

Now the tricky part comes when the two cards flipped over have an equal value, this is called a "war".  At a war, the players each flip another card on the top of their deck over, and whoever has the highest value card gets all the cards on the table.  My question is, what is the chance that these two cards also have equal value?  So, the probability of having two cards out of $52$, be equal, then the next two cards be equal.

I keep arriving at this number: $\frac{3}{49} + \frac{1}{49} = \frac{4}{49} = 0.0816$.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ignore everything except for the two flips that result in war. Given that there was a war on the first flip, the deck has lost two cards of equal rank.

Then $50$ cards remain. There are $12$ complete ranks of $4$ cards each. Each of those ranks has $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possible pairs. The $13$th rank is the one that was drawn for the first war, and there is only $1$ remaining pair of that rank.

Overall there are $(12\cdot6)+1=73$ pairs left in the deck of $50$ cards.

So the probability of a second war is $\frac{73}{\binom{50}{2}}=\frac{73}{1225}\approx5.96\%$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!  I was wondering what was wrong with my calculation though, do you by any chance know?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about where the numbers in your calculation came from?

Comment: Yes.  After the first war, I assume 2 cards have been lost.  So, instead of 52 cards, there are now 50 cards.  When one person flips a card over, there are now 49 cards, with 3 cards able to match its rank.  Giving 3/49.  However, there is the chance that the person gets the card of the same rank as the first war.  And the chance to match that is 1/49.  So I have 3/49 + 1/49.

Comment: Ah, got it. So, you need to assign weights to each of those fractions. There is a $\frac{48}{50}$ probability that the first card flipped was not another of the same rank from the first war, and a $\frac{2}{50}$ probability it was one of the same rank from the first war. So the calculation should be $\frac{48}{50}\cdot\frac{3}{49}+\frac{2}{50}\cdot\frac{1}{49}$. This results in the same answer I got the other way.

Comment: @DreiCleaner, sorry, I didn't see your comment here until just now, after posting an answer saying the same thing.

Comment: Great minds think alike!

Comment: @DreiCleaner, I was thinking much the same!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to the OP's request, in comments below DreiCleaner's answer, to explain what is wrong in their (mis)calculation ${3\over49}+{1\over49}$.

The OP is quite right that if the third card flipped is *matches* the rank of the cards in the first war, then there is only a $1/49$ chance the fourth card will match the third. But this (the third card matching the first to) only happens with probability $2/50$ -- that is, the third card must be one of the $2$ cards of the same rank from the first war, out of $50$ cards available. Similarly, if the third card is *different* from the rank of the first war, which happens with probability $48/50$, then the fourth card will match it with probability $3/49$. So a correct calculation of the probability of a second war is

$${48\over50}\cdot{3\over49}+{2\over50}\cdot{1\over49}={24\cdot3+1\over25\cdot49}={73\over1225}$$

as in DreiCleaner's answer.

Comment: Ah, I see DreiCleaner said all this in a reply to the OP's comment.